# How much vertical weight/height do I need to store 33 kWh of energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, newtonian-gravity, mass, batteries

My question is the feasibility of a vertical mechanical weight battery, but unlike previous questions, I wanted to give a precise scenario and see if my math is right (which I doubt)

First, it takes 1.345 watts to lift 1 lb 1 vertical foot in 1 second.

Assume the battery weighs 100 lb per cubic foot, so a block of weight 4 feet per side would weigh 6,400 lbs.

Therefore it would take 8,600 watts (or 8.6 kw) to lift this weight 1 foot (not sure if the "per second" aspect matters).

Now, that it has 8.6 kw of potential energy, I can now power my house at night by dropping the weight slowly.

If a typical home uses 1000 kWh energy per month, thats about 33 kwh per day.

So  if I want my battery to store 33 kwh of power per day, instead of 8.6kw, I either need to quadruple my weight or the lifting height (increase to 4 ft instead of 1 ft lift height).

One main unaccounted factor I can think of is inefficiency of the system, but even at say 50%, I would offset that loss by doubling my height or weight once again.  My thought is a weight battery to store solar, so a second issue would be cloudy days, so maybe double or triple the height/weight again.

Yes, I have already seen that large scale  pilot project with cranes & blocks.

Is my math right? Does this sound feasible?

Comment: Kilowatt is a unit of power, not energy. You can't store kilowatts.

Comment: For units of energy you might want to use a watt second or its equivalent a joule, or a kilowatt hour or its equivalent 3.6 megajoules.

Answer (score 3):

The power equation you have is causing confusion.  That deals with all sorts of nuances about how you would have to apply the energy, but you're concerned with how large the block must be, and how high it must be raised.  These can be done entirely with energy terms.

One of the extraordinarily nifty thing about energy is that it is conserved.  This ends up meaning that it doesn't matter *how* you lift the block.  All that matters is where the block ends up.  In particular, the equation you need is
$$E=mgh$$

Where $E$ is the gravitational potential energy you're storing in the block, $m$ is its mass, $g$ is the acceleration of gravity, and $h$ is the height you raise it to.

We can rearrange the equation to $h=\frac{E}{mg}$ to get the height you have to raise the block to as a function of mass.  Given $E=33000\;\text{J}$ and $g=9.8\;\text{m/s}$  (I have converted kJ to J to put everything in base units, just for ease of use), we get $h\approx 3367[\frac{\text m}{\text{kg}}]\cdot\frac{1}{m}$.

If I take your 6,400 pound block, and convert that to kg, I get 2903kg, so you would need to lift the block 1.16m to store 33kJ.  Since you are using English units, I'll convert that to about 3.8 ft.

Or do you?

You'll note that I quietly fixed your energy units.  When you say 33kW, that's a *power* measure.  If you're measuring energy, as in the first part of the phrase "energy per day", its joules.  I silently just put 33kJ into that equation, just to run the numbers.  However, given that your "33k" number is really close to "30kWh", which is the average consumption of a household per day, my guess is that you really intended to write 33kWh... that is "thirty three kilowatt **hours**."

No worries, we can run these numbers too!  30kWh can be turned into joules pretty easily.  1 kilowatt-second is 1 joule, so 1 kilowatt-hour must be 3600 kilojoules.  So you really wanted 108,000kJ (same as 108MJ, same as 180,000,000J).

Plugging that number in, we find:

$h\approx 11,020,408[\frac{\text m}{\text{kg}}]\cdot\frac{1}{m}$

And with your 2903kg block, that's $h\approx 3,796[\text m]$

For reference, that's about ten times the height of the Empire State Building.

We're going to need a bigger block.

There are systems which store energy by lifting heavy things.  They tend to lift heavier things than a mere 3 ton block.  The systems I have read about put a multiple-acre inflatable bladder under several meters of sand.  Filling the bladder with water lifts the sand, just like you lifted a block.  However, because it is distributed and stays on the ground, it is much easier to work with.

For another point of view, I found [this video](https://youtu.be/Blh-pN65aTg?t=148) of lifting a Ford Raptor using a home lift.  This lift is connected to the house with a standard extension cable, so it is clearly pulling no where near the amperage of a whole house.  Yet it lifts the 6000 pound Raptor much faster than you are talking about lifting the block.

Comment: Cort, (just a suggestion) if I wanted to generate 33kW of energy in the real world, I would have to factor in the efficiency of the devices that were recovering that power from stored gravitational potential energy.

Comment: @DavidWhite "if I wanted to generate 33kW of energy" Once again, kW is not a unit of energy.

Comment: @DavidWhite True, one does have to take into account such inefficiencies.  However, when the initial calculations are quite literally off by four orders of magnitude, it's like accounting for the mass of dust that has accumulated on a bulldozer.  Large generators are typically on the order of 99% efficient, and motors seem to be similar.

Comment: The crane system claims to be 85% efficient.

Comment: Wait,  https://gravitricity.com/projects/ , https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/04/gravity-based-batteries-try-beat-their-chemical-cousins-winches-weights-and-mine-shafts, https://www.spglobal.com/platts/en/market-insights/latest-news/electric-power/083120-gravitricity-starts-work-on-250-kw-uk-energy-storage-demonstrator

Comment: @hippypink Yes, you can do it.  They are looking at a 250kW system that can drop the weight in 11 seconds, which means it stores 0.76kWh -- a tiny fraction of the energy you are talking about... and you can see the size of the device.

Comment: @hippypink That is, assuming I interpreted your mistaken units correctly.  It would be *much* easier for people to answer your question if you would go back and edit in the consistent units.  I'm still running on the assumption that the goal is 33kWh, because you used the word "energy" and that is a reasonable energy number for a daily household consumption.

Comment: Obviously I am confused a bit still. So 250kw is not the same as 250kwh, which would be 250x3600 = 900,000 kw), right?  So how useful would their protoype be in storing energy for a home?  2 seconds worth?  and for $1M cost. They would have to reduce costs by 1000's of times, and considering how large this is, seems unwieldy for a system for multiple homes.

Comment: i updated the question to show kwh.

Comment: @hippypink kW is a unit of [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)) and kWh is a unit of [energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy).  1kWh is the amount of energy consume by something using 1kW for 1 hour, or 2kW for 30 minutes, or 0.5kW for 2 hours, etc.  So, just to put numbers on it, that tower you linked, generating 250 kW for 11 seconds stores 0.76kWh.  At the average power consumption of a house (33kWh / 24 hours = 1.375kW), that stores 0.76kWh/1.375kWh = 0.55hours, or about 33 minutes worth of energy for one household.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Going to look into pumping water up the hill next door to a resevoir instead. Since a rock/sand based system would need to be incredibly massive or lifted incredibly high :)